# Finding a word and/or variable in Word Document and changing it to a Bold Font

Tags: powershell, vbscript, fonts, ms-word

I have a script where I am replacing a bookmark in a word document with text from a xml.

I have hard coded a few words into the word document via the bookmark properties. I am trying to turn the font of the strings I hardcoded into the document into bold and increase the font size

***StigData is predefined earlier in my script...
The script works fine its just not bolding the font.***

```
$template = "Template.docx"
$wd = New-Object –comobject Word.Application
$doc=$wd.documents.Add($template)

foreach ($stigDataItem in $stigData) 
{
   $title = $stigDataItem.title
   $check = $stigDataItem.group.Rule.check.'check-content'
   $ft = $stigDataItem.group.rule.fixtext.innerxml

   $doc.Bookmarks.Item("AllStigInfo").Range.Text ="FixText" + "`r`n" + $ft + "`r`n" +"`r`n"
   $doc.Bookmarks.Item("AllStigInfo").Range.Text ="Check Content" + "`r`n" + $check + "`r`n"
   $doc.Bookmarks.Item("AllStigInfo").Range.Text =$title + "`r`n"

}

$selection = $wd.selection
$selection.Font.Bold = $True
$stringcheck = "Check Content"
$selection.TypeText($stringcheck)

$doc.SaveAs([ref]$newfile)
$doc.Close()
$wd.Quit()
Remove-Variable wd
```

I attempted to select the words I need to replace and replace it with a bold font with the section:

```
$selection = $wd.selection
$selection.Font.Bold = $True
$stringcheck = "Check Content"
$selection.TypeText($stringcheck)
```

However that just added a bold word to the document.

I am trying to bold everywhere that says `FixText`, `Check Content`, and `$title`. Also making `$title` a bigger font.

Also tried referring to https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/02/01/how-can-i-boldface-a-specific-word-throughout-a-microsoft-word-document/ but it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered two ways of doing this. I used Find and Replace method in Word.
In PowerShell I ended up using

**Method 1**

```
$searchText=$replaceText= 'Check Content'
$wdReplaceAll  = 2
$wd=New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$wd.Visible=$false
$doc = $wd.Documents.Open($newfile)
$wd.Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = $true
$wd.Selection.Find.Execute($searchText, $false, $true, $false, $false, $false, $true, $false, $true, $replaceText, $wdReplaceAll)
```

**Method 2**

I also found a VBscript that looks for the specific word and replace and changed it to bold. Using PowerShell to pass the variable `$newfile`.

Site: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/02/01/how-can-i-boldface-a-specific-word-throughout-a-microsoft-word-document/

```
#invoke script and passed $newfile to vbscript (added in my Powershell script)
$arg1 = "$newfile"
$arg2 = "$title"
$command = “cmd /C cscript 'boldfont.vbs' $arg1”
invoke-expression $command

#vbscript I created
Const wdReplaceAll  = 2
Set objWord = CreateObject(“Word.Application”)
objWord.Visible = True
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(“$newfile”)
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.Find.Text = “Check Content”
objSelection.Find.Forward = TRUE
objSelection.Find.MatchWholeWord = TRUE
objSelection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = True
objSelection.Find.Execute ,,,,,,,,,,wdReplaceAll
```

I will use this to change `Fix Text` and `$title`.

I wanted to share it. Might could help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PowerShell, but the logic seems clear enough so that my suggestion should work:

You should declare a Word.Range object or objects and assign the Bookmark.Range(s) to it/them so that you can afterwards work directly with the Range. (Bookmarks are deleted as soon as something is assigned to their Range, which is why you can't continue on using them for further actions.)

Working with Ranges is preferable to using the Selection object, and you can have more than one (the Application supports only one Selection).

So something like this:

```
$rngBookmark = $doc.Bookmarks.Item("AllStigInfo").Range
$rngBookmark.Text ="FixText" + "`r`n" + $ft + "`r`n" +"`r`n"
$rngBookmark.Font.Bold = $True
```

If you want to bold only "FixText" and nothing that follows it in the assignment to the `Text` property, then:

```
$rngBookmark = $doc.Bookmarks.Item("AllStigInfo").Range
$rngBookmark.Text ="FixText"
$rngBookmark.Font.Bold = $True
//You need to figure out the syntax for the Collapse method
//I just put in the way I'd use it from VB.NET, with full qualification
$rngBookmark.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
$rngBookmark.Text = "`r`n" + $ft + "`r`n" +"`r`n"
```

Collapsing the Range is similar to pressing left- / right-arrow on the keyboard to "collapse" a selection to a cursor point.

Comment: Ahh I get what you are saying. That's a good idea. I'll look around for it and try your way... Thanks a lot

Comment: @slong16 Does that mean it works, but you don't understand it? Or it doesn't work?

Comment: No it didn't work. I could use the first portion because I didn't want the whole thing bold, only the word Fix Text. 
You said I should find the collapse method for excel...I could not find one that works for me.  I use book ranges because of the amount of text that I use... It exceeds the character limit.

Comment: @slong16 I've never mentioned Excel... Word's Range object has a Collapse method, you don't need to "find" anything, I was just not sure the syntax was correct for the language environment you're using. The last part of your comment is completely unclear and, if it's important information, should be added to your Question using the [edit] link below it.

Comment: I meant Word not excel. I understand you didn't know the syntax for PowerShell. I was saying I could not find the correct collapse method syntax for PowerShell. The information was not important so I didn't put it in my question. Anyhow, thanks for giving me a direction to go in.